# mongodb with typescript `toArray` method not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, typechecking

I'm using Visual studio with typescript.  Everything in this code compiles.  According to [the mongoDB docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) I'm using `toArray` correctly.  I'm a little new to typescript, so I don't know if this is a typescript error or mongodb.  **The `tests` variable seems to have a method `toArray` but when I call it nothing returns.**  The `console.log` call isn't even ran.  According to the docs and the [typescript samples](http://typescript.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#samples/imageboard/db.ts) this is the correct way to do it.  Can anyone share with me any errors in my code, or the "correct" way to do this?

```
///<reference path="c:\DefinitelyTyped\mongodb\mongodb.d.ts"/>

import mongodb = require("mongodb")

var server = new mongodb.Server('localhost',27017, { auto_reconnect: true})
var db = new mongodb.Db('test', server, { w: 1 });

export interface Test {
    _id: mongodb.ObjectID;
    a: number;
}

db.open(function () { });

export function getTest(callback: (test: any) => void): void {

    db.collection('test', function (err, test_collection) {
        // test_collection.find().toArray -- this doesn't work either
        test_collection.find(function (err, tests) {
            console.log(tests, 'from getTest') // log's an object with `toArray` method
            tests.toArray(function (err, docs) { // nothing returned.  Seems like the callback isn't ran
                if (err) { console.log(err) }
                console.log(docs, 'from toArray')
                callback(docs)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem seems to be not placing your function within the `db.open` method's callback in general:

```js
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

var server = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true });
var db = new mongodb.Db('test', server, { w: 1 });

db.open(function() {

  db.createCollection('test', function(err, collection) {

    collection.find().toArray(function(err,docs) {

      console.log( docs );

    });

  });

});
```

You generally need to make sure a connection is open before doing anything

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for the quick response.  I now am using mongoDB.MongoClient to connect.